# authentication cookie

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, webforms, authentication

Using Asp.Net MVC 1, I have my "log on" control/page...I check the "remember me" checkbox and hit submit.. in my controller I have:

```
FormsAuth.SignIn(userName, password, rememberMe)
```

This method creates the persisted cookie .ASPXAUTH and everything is good at this point.. I put a breakpoint in other controller, and I noticed that once I'm loggued to the website.. for the next "postback" or page refresh... the cookie .ASPXAUTH has gone from the cookies collection... so.. when I'm back to the site, even when I selected the option "remember me".. it ask my credentials again with the login form...

any idea why this is happening?

---

**UPDATED:**

I think this is not a problem with MVC. I created a new application with WebForms, the page contains 1 textbox, 1 button to generate the cookie.. and other button to write the cookie in a label.. http://screencast.com/t/MjQ1MTVmYWU

this is my code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("test");
    cookie.Value = TextBox1.Text;
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);

    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}//with a breakpoint here, I "watch" the Response.Cookies collection and I can see my "test" item there.

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{//with a breakpoint here. the Response.Cookies collection is empty.
    Label1.Text = Response.Cookies["test"].Value ?? "null";
}
```

I'm having the same result.. the cookie is added correctly to the Response.Cookies collection, but in the second postback the collection is empty again..

the result.. the label gets the value "null".

maybe some configuration? I have never worked before with cookies.

Comment: I also have tryed adding my own cookies: Response.Cookies.Add(mycookie); and it is added successfully but for the next "postback" the cookies collection is empty

Comment: Is this happening in all browsers?

Comment: what browser? arent you in incognito mode?

Comment: I've tryed in both IE8 and Mozilla Firefox 3.6.8

Comment: I have noticed something else.. I'm using the tool fiddler with Mozilla.. and while Visual Studio 2008 debugger tells me that the Cookies collection is empty... the request/response catched by fiddler shows me the cookies...  but I'm not able to use the fiddler with IE and localhost...

Comment: When you say, "...when i´m back to the site..."; did you do a logout in the middle and then returned to the site? or you left without doing logout?

Comment: Why do I have the feeling that this *other controller* (the one that you are saying is not seeing the cookie) is part of another application hosted on a different domain?

Comment: @uvita no, I don't logout.. I close the browser and open it again..

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov it's part of the same website. if you see my update my real problem is that the cookies are not being persisted after postbacks. btw Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

As I said before this is the first time I work with cookies...

the problem was that..for retreiving the value I have to use the collection Request.Cookies instead of Response.Cookies... this sounds reasonable because the request is sent from the browser.. (my fault xP)

so, in summary...

1. Response.Cookies to create cookies
2. the cookie is stored in the browser
3. Request.Cookies to retrieve the cookie's value

Thanks everybody!